# How do I file a bug on a PPA upstream with the maintainers using Launchpad?

Tags: wine, ppa, launchpad, bug-reporting

I thought about reporting a bug about a package from the wine PPA, but neither https://bugs.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine has an option to post a new bug report no https://answers.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine has an option to post a new question. But there are old bug reports and questions listed there.

I wonder how I can do this.

The standard `ubuntu-bug`way doesn't work for a package from PPA:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8 LANGUAGE=en LANG=en_US.UTF8 DISPLAY= ubuntu-bug wine1.7

*** Collecting problem information

The collected information can be sent to the developers to improve the
application. This might take a few minutes.
............

*** Problem in wine1.7

The problem cannot be reported:

This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.

Press any key to continue... 

No pending crash reports. Try --help for more information.
$
```

Comment: What about the standard way: `ubuntu-bug <name-of-package>`?

Comment: @muru The standard way doesn't work for a package from a PPA (I'll paste the details into my question now).

Comment: You could contact [Scott Ritchie](https://launchpad.net/~scottritchie), the owner of [Ubuntu Wine Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine).

Comment: @EricCarvalho Well, I've written down my report as https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39226 in the hope that it will also reach the right people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launchpad doesn't have the facility to host bug trackers for PPAs, except in informal ways (some PPAs have an associated project for the purpose of bug reporting).  If you aren't told otherwise, the only thing you can do is contact the owner of the PPA directly.

Comment: But somehow https://bugs.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine has some bugs. That--in the first place--made me wonder: how did those bugs got assigned to ubuntu-wine and how I could do the same.

Comment: Those are bugs filed elsewhere (for example on the official wine package in Ubuntu) that the ubuntu-wine team is assigned to or subscribed to.  That's of no help to you in working out an appropriate bug *target* in this case.