# How do I install VLC 3.0 on Ubuntu Zesty 17.04?

Tags: ppa, vlc, 17.04

I'm having a difficulty installing VLC 3.0 in Ubuntu Zesty. Using the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily). I added it using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
```

And `apt-cache show` has it listed,

```
apt-cache show vlc | grep Version
Version: 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu16.04.1
Version: 2.2.4-14ubuntu2
```

but when I try to install `3.0.0` with `sudo apt-get install vlc=3.*` I get,

```
sudo apt-get install vlc=3.*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu16.04.1' ( [amd64]) for 'vlc'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.6) but it is not installable or
                libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.6) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) or
                libgles1
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there another PPA that provides VLC 3.0 in Ubuntu Zesty? It seems that libavcodec-ffmpeg56 was renamed,

```
$ apt-cache search libavcodec ffmpeg
libavcodec-extra57 - FFmpeg library with additional de/encoders for audio/video codecs
```

And that now vlc-3.* needs to be built against the new library (libavcodec-extra57) and have its manifest updated from old name (libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56)

I can't file a bug on this either [because Launchpad doesn't support that.](https://askubuntu.com/q/671099/29097) All I can do is write the maintainer using the Launchpad contact forum, which I did. No response back.

Comment: That vlc ppa is a joke, it's just automated builds that keep failing. For instance the last 16.04 build that actually succeeded was on 2016/08/13. Likely there was never a 17.04 build that actually built..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can install a snap of vlc 3:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

It will be installed alongside your original vlc (if you don't uninstall the original vlc).

Comment: If you need the snap vlc to browse/open outside of your $HOME then remove it `sudo snap remove vlc` & re-install with `sudo snap install --classic  vlc`

Comment: Worth mentioning: the VLC packaged as a Snap was last updated on Jan 20, 2017. So I'm not sure if this is still maintained, but it's working now. =)

Comment: Omg! Using snap method needs 115MB of Data!!

Comment: Also worth mentioning, this version doesn't play mp4

Comment: Doesn't seem to exist anymore, sadly.

Comment: @doug, I tried --classic but no joy!  I still can't access an NFS mount which has all my media.  SNAP FAIL!
Would be nice if someone just made a bloody ppa like the old fashion way so we can get the latest VLC via apt!  Waiting for snap to sort out the philosphical-ideological cr@p about restrictions really limits usability for the common folk for a media player which should be able to play media from any location!

Comment: @DanglingPointer , the current vlc snap &  snapd can access mounted volumes without --classic or anything, maybe snapd in 17.04 is deficient. Seeing as though 17.04 is EOL & gets not more updates try a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: @doug, apologies mate, forgot to state that I'm on 16.04.4 LTS which is a couple of generations older than OP's

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `flatpak` over `snap`. It's open source and multi arch application sandboxing and distribution framework for Linux.
It's easy to use and you can run closed source applications such as `Steam`, `Sublimetext` in it.

You can install it via `ppa` or build it straight from `github`, it doesn't take much time.
What I did for my Ubuntu 16.04

```
mkdir FLATPAK; cd FLATPAK

git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/ostreedev/ostree.git
cd ostree
git submodule update --init
env NOCONFIGURE=1 ./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak.git
cd flatpak
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/PipeWire/pipewire.git
cd pipewire
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal.git
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.git
./autogen.sh
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

then add application repositories to install applications.

```
flatpak --user remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Finally install `VLC`

```
flatpak --user install flathub org.videolan.VLC
```

and launch it via

```
flatpak run org.videolan.VLC
```

To see available applications and runtimes

```
 flatpak --user remote-ls -d flathub
```

For more info check out [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/)

***EDIT: I added new dependencies and changed order of installation sequence.***

Comment: Whilst your instructions did not work for me (too many missing dependencies etc) I would like to thank you for suggesting Flatpak. I installed following instructions found here https://flatpak.org/getting.html This version of VLC is working perfectly(Snap version was useless) Chromecast support at last :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have added the wrong ppa source, or the ppa isn't working 100% for 17.04 now. The linked ppc home says for 17.04 these should be somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list*`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu zesty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu zesty main
```

From the packages it wants to install and depends on, I'm seeing a lot of "16.04" that doesn't sound right for your "17.04" system. Like:

```
Version: 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu**16.04.1**  
...  
Depends: vlc-nox (= 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu**16.04.1**) but...  
Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu**16.04.1**) but...  
Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~~git20160813+r65787+62~ubuntu**16.04.1**) but...
```

Comment: The 16.04 point is valid, but `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily` adds those very lines, except it does it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-zesty.list` so your sources.list is unmodified (still works with apt though). `apt-add-repository` also brings in the ppa's key so the packages can be tested for signature.

Comment: That's not a good sign... I'm thinking the ppa itself isn't configured or working right for 17.04. I tried browsing it manually and I did see some source files with "17.04" in the names [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vlc/), but no .deb files for 17.04. Maybe a 16.10 deb might work, or compile from source?

Answer (score 0):

I had the videolan/master-daily PPA enabled though my intention was not to use 3.0 back when I upgraded to 17.04, so I continued to use what I thought were the latest 2.x builds. I just noticed that some icons in the interface have changed and checked the about dialog to find out that I'm using 3.0 now.

```
Package: vlc
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: video
Installed-Size: 220
Maintainer: Debian Multimedia Maintainers <pkg-multimedia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1
Provides: mp3-decoder
Depends: vlc-bin (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-plugin-base (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-plugin-qt (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-plugin-video-output (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-l10n (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1)
Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-plugin-video-splitter (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1), vlc-plugin-visualization (= 3.0.0~~git20170829+r71452+74~ubuntu17.04.1)
```