# Installing VLC on ubuntu 16.04 using a .deb file

Tags: 16.04, vlc, deb

I have tried to install vlc on 16.04 by downloading a `.deb` file from [this debian packages site](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/vlc-data/download).

But when I went to terminal and did this:
[image: in terminal extracting the .deb file]
nothing happened. VLC didn't get installed.
Can you suggest a solution?

I wish to install VLC using `.deb` file and not use `apt-get` because it is blocked for my system.

Comment: Please replace the screenshot by copying text from terminal.

Comment: What is blocked?

Comment: `vlc-data` is just a part of VLC containing some extra data files needed for the player, not the player itself. Instead of struggling to work around a broken package system, you should really investigate into that and fix it before, then you can use `sudo apt install vlc`.

Comment: can you tell me where to find the complete package

Comment: Better to use snap --> http://www.askubuntu.com/a/915141/631600

Comment: Also, why not just install from the Ubuntu repo ? Picking different .deb packages from various places is a recipe for problems later on. If you what you want is to get the latest version of VLC, use the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I use gdebi package installer. It automatically handels nearly all dependancy and problem in any .deb file. I will suggest you to try the same.

Answer (score -1):

Have u checked if it was installed or not?

You can click on ubuntu at top left and search vlc it might be already installed.

I know you may not want but you can install vlc using apt also

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```